# checking if data from input from react matches with any data in the backend django

Tags: django, reactjs

im using django as my backend. I want an efficient way to check if a data from an input exist in my database.

Initially im fetching the all the objects i have in my database to the fronetend then comparing it. But now the data in the database has increased and fetching all to the frontend isnt efficient. help please

Answer (score 0):

make an `onChange` event of that input, so every time you change the input value, you will make a call to API. I recommend using `axios` (documentation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)

It would be something like this:

```
handleOnChange = ({currentTarget}) => {
    axios.get(`/api/${currentTarget.value}`).then(({data}) => {
        //data is the response from API
    })
}

return (
    <input onChange={handleOnChange} />
)
```